# XAMPP apache service not start

Tags: php, apache, xampp

When i trying to start apache services i show the following erron in error block panel

> 11:51:30 AM  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped 
>   11:51:30 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>   11:51:30 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>  
>   11:51:30 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   11:51:30 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   11:51:30 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>   11:51:30 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
>   11:51:30 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums

plese someone help me

Comment: Your apache port is being used by some other service check the port through task manager

Comment: logout and quit skype if open

Comment: have you using  Skype???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello if you are using Skype then from Skype Tools->options->Advanced->Connection
in this check Use-port there one text box may be there default port using 80 so make that box empty. and save logout from Skype and login again now your skype use port other than 80 so now your Apache is working fine.

And there is other solution is also you can also change your default port for Apache 80 to other from Apache `httpd.conf` `ServerName localhost:80` to any other free port like `ServerName localhost:81` may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I figured it out:

1. In Control Panel, click on Apache ---- Config button and open the file in the first line (httpd.conf), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkjMs.png)
2. Search for these lines
    `#Listen 12.34.56.78:80`

   `Listen 80`

   `ServerName localhost:80`

And replace `80` in these lines by another number `x`, probably a unique one to avoid duplicate. Eg, 2017.

3. In Control Panel, click on Config button in upper right corner, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSMQL.png).

   `Service and Port Settings` > `Main Port`: replace the old one with `x`

That's how mine works. Hope it helps you.