# WAMP server won't prefix localhost and suffix port number

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, wampserver

### Problem 1 :

The folders listed under `Your Projects` doesn't have the `http://localhost/` prefix by default.

So instead of going to `http://localhost/your_project/` , it goes to `http://your_project/`

### Problem 2 :

And after changing my default Apache port number to `8085` (due to Skype conflict), the port number wont automatically get suffixed to `http://localhost/`.

So instead of going to `http://localhost:8085/my_project`, it simply goes to `http://localhost/my_project/` (which obviously does not work).

Comment: For Skype port issues no need to change default 80 port you can try this solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429409/xampp-apache-service-not-start/37429619#37429619

Comment: Yep bro that's really useful. But the main point here was that the port number doesn't get suffixed if we change the port number. Skype is not the only conflict that arises with port number ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution to problem 1 :

Locate and open `index.php` from www directory (`C:\wamp\www\index.php`)

Find this line :

```
$UrlPort = $port !== "80" ? ":".$port : '';
```

Change it to :

```
$UrlPort = $port !== "80" ? ":".$port : ':8085';
```

where 8085 is the new port number in your case

---

### Solution to problem 2 :

Locate and open `wampmanager.conf` from wamp installation directory (`C:\wamp\wampmanager.conf`)

Find this line :

```
urlAddLocalhost = "off"
```

Change it to :

```
urlAddLocalhost = "on"
```

---